# what is the name of this design (anti-)pattern?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, design-patterns

Recently I took a project which was initially a thick client Java application written in Swing. Later they got a requirement to support http requests. So they implemented a code like this:

```
public void handleRequest(...) {
    if(contextPath.equals("purchase-product")) {
        getMainPanel().getPurchasePanelButton().doClick();
        getMainPanel().getPurchasePanel().selectProductById(productId);
        if(getMainPanel().getPurchasePanel().getPurchaseButton().isEnabled()) {
           getMainPanel().getPurchasePanel().getPurchaseButton().doClick();
           ...
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

My first thought was WTF. Weren't they familiar with MVC pattern?

But then I was thinking they implemented the code like this to be able to do Swing GUI tests via http requests using JMeter or SoapUI instead of complicated GUI frameworks like Squish.

My question is do people use similar technique to simplify their component tests? What is the name of this (anti-) pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote for "[Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)". Anyway it's clearly the opposite of the useful pattern "[Tell, Don't Ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)" with all those accessor (get) methods exposing implementation details at every possible level of abstraction. It's remarkable in its disregard for Demeter, which is also mentioned in that second reference.